Order By Spark with a variable
I am trying to use OrderBy on my dataframe but, I want to use a variable to refer to the columns for which I want to order the dataframe.
The variable that I'm using is:
city_col = "city_col"
And I'm trying the following statement:
sdf.orderBy(cols=city_col,ascending=True)
But it's not working, the instruction was to use a variable to sort, for that reason I am using the variable.

Take out cols= and it should work

cols is a positional argument, rather than a keyword argument. Positional arguments are represented with a preceding * like how we see *cols in the documentation for the orderBy function
